# Loop in multidimensional array not showing what is expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Hello I try trying to compare some values in a multidimensional array but when I try to console.log don't show anything I think is correct but not showing. Did I did something wrong?.

```
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

var position = 0;
for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length;j++){
    for(var g = 0; g < arr[i].length;g++){
      if(j != g && arr[i][j][0] === arr[i][g][0]){
        console.log(arr[i][j][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
//expecting fish, bone;
```

The problem is in the if statement but I can't see why.

Comment: The third *for*, in the condition is not `arr[i].length` but `arr[i][j].length`.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Why? It work when is just the `j != g` but when i compare the `arr[i][j][0] === arr[i][g][0]` doesn't work can you explain or give me a example?

Comment: While what you are attempting to do is not really clear, `arr[i].length`, is correct for what you are actually doing.

Comment: @ReySomething the first case when `j != g` is when `i = 0, j = 0 and g = 1`, if you look at your map you're comparing: 'cat' with 'dog'. And the same for any other cases. Please explain what you're expecting.

Comment: The problem is in your data (or in your logic) because arr[i][j][0] === arr[i][g][0] only when j == g

Comment: How can `fish` and `bone` come out?

Comment: @Bob__ I add what i expect to get (fish, bone), I am just trying to to compare the position 0 to get the and if they are the same and the position 1 is same then print it.

Comment: So, maybe you should check for `arr[i][j][1] === arr[i][g][1]` too...

Comment: @Bob__ but the position 0 have to be the same. in case that the is more values.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is not clear.  The `if` statement that you are using will always compare `'cat'` to `'dog'` which will result in no output.

Below is your code, modified to show what you are comparing. In general, adding additional logging output is a reasonable way to debug by providing information as to what is really happening.

Note: I changed the start position for the `g` loop to `j + 1`. You will have already compared all entries in a prior run of the loop for those where `g < j` and your don't want to compare things against themselves. Obviously, this means that your `if` statement no longer needs to check for `j == g`.

Your comparisons are:

```
cat === dog is false
cat === dog is false
cat === dog is false
```

Given that all of the conditions you evaluate in your `if` statement are `false`, you don't get any output from your `console.log(arr[i][j][1]);`

```js
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

var position = 0;
for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length;j++){
    //You will have already compared all entries with g<j and we don't
    //  want to compare against itself.
    for(var g = j + 1; g < arr[i].length;g++){
      console.log(arr[i][j][0] + ' === ' + arr[i][g][0] 
                  + ' ([' + i + '][' + j + '][0] === [' + i + '][' + g + '][0])'
                  + " is " + (arr[i][j][0] === arr[i][g][0]));
      if(arr[i][j][0] === arr[i][g][0]){
        console.log('Match: ' + arr[i][j][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, based on the data you have, what you might be attempting to do is compare the kind of thing the animal is playing with/eating. If this is the case, the issue may be that you are confusing which index is for which portion of the multidimensional array.

```js
var arr = [
    //         [a][0][c]                     [a][1][c]
    //[a][0][0]         [a][0][1]   [a][0][0]         [a][0][1]
    [[  'cat',            'fish' ],[  'dog',            'meat' ]],  // [0][b][c]
    [[  'cat',            'toy'  ],[  'dog',            'bone' ]],  // [1][b][c]
    [[  'cat',            'fish' ],[  'dog',            'bone' ]]   // [2][b][c]
];

var position = 0;
for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
  for(var iP = i + 1; iP < arr.length;iP++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length;j++){
      console.log(arr[i][j][1] + ' === ' + arr[iP][j][1] 
                  + ' ([' + i + '][' + j + '][1] === [' + iP + '][' + j + '][1])'
                  + " is " + (arr[i][j][1] === arr[iP][j][1]));
      if(arr[i][j][1] === arr[iP][j][1]){
        console.log('Match: ' + arr[i][j][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intent, you have to change your loops and the condition:

```js
var arr = [
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'meat']],
    [['cat', 'toy'],['dog', 'bone']],
    [['cat', 'fish'],['dog', 'bone']]
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  // compare only different rows
  for (var k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
    // inside each row, compare the columns elements
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j][0] === arr[k][j][0] && arr[i][j][1] === arr[k][j][1]) {
         //  ^^^ compare      ^^^ different   ^^^  rows        ^^^
         console.log(arr[i][j][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```